# Handling List data in SharePoint 2010 for Worfklows in Visual Studio 2010 with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, delimiter, sharepoint-workflow

I am writing a custom workflow for SharePoint in c# in VS 2010

My current aim is to take a SharePoint List data field that is delimited by ' ; ' to split the data and re-enter it into several different List fields if they are blank.

If this i possible in SharePoint designer do let me know the secret, however this is my visual studio efforts thus far:

```
namespace DataFlow1.Workflow1
{
public sealed partial class Workflow1 : SequentialWorkflowActivity
{
    public Workflow1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Guid workflowId = default(System.Guid);
    public SPWorkflowActivationProperties workflowProperties = new     SPWorkflowActivationProperties();

    private void onWorkflowActivated1_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
    {
        SPSite mySourceSite = new SPSite("http://win-    hnb91nnab2g/Lists/Lookup%20List/AllItems.aspx/");
        SPWeb mySourceWeb = mySourceSite.OpenWeb();
        SPList mySourceList = mySourceWeb.Lists["Lookup List"];
        SPListItem mySourceListItem = workflowProperties.Item;

        string SourceTitle = mySourceListItem["Title"].ToString();
             //test


            char[] delimiterChars = { ';' };
            string SourceData = mySourceListItem["Data In"].ToString();
            string[] SourceDataSplit = SourceData.Split(delimiterChars);




            SPSite myDestinationSite = new SPSite("http://win-hnb91nnab2g/Lists/Output%20List/AllItems.aspx/");
            SPWeb myDestinationWeb = myDestinationSite.OpenWeb();
            SPList myDestinationList = myDestinationWeb.Lists["Output List"];
            SPListItem myDestinationListItem = myDestinationList.Items.Add();

            myDestinationListItem["Title"] = SourceTitle;
            myDestinationListItem["Data Out"] = SourceDataSplit;

            myDestinationWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            myDestinationListItem.Update();
            myDestinationWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The code as is debugs and did copy the data from one field to another **before** i attempted delimiters.

I am not hoping for a solution but any advice were to find examples of what i am trying to achieve inside the boundaries of a workflow would be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou.